# Run PHP code on page with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My whole HTML page is in a PHP file. (index.php)
This is how my index.php looks like:

```
some HTML code...
Kiválasztott hét: <select id="hetvalaszto" onchange="changeWeek()">
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","imreigye_wp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8mb4');

    $sql = "select * from rendelesiidok order by het";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $prevhet = "";

    $hszarr = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if ($row['Het'] == $prevhet) {} else if ($row['Het'] == "999") 
            echo "<option value=" . $row['Het'] . ">Alap hét</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value=" . $row['Het'] . ">" . $row['Het'] . ". hét</option>";
        $prevhet = $row['Het'];
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
</select>
...some more HTML code
```

The PHP code populates a dropdown-list. What I want to do is the following: I want to re-populate the dropdown list using javascript or jquery after the page is loaded. For that, I need to run the php code again.

Comment: U need to use AJAX request that run by javascript function after page load

Comment: why you want this in javascript?